# Strange scope issues in bash while loop

Tags: arrays, bash

I have the following code in a script which SHOULD work but does not provide array elements when it exist the inner loop. The variable IPLISTING is global in scope.

```
declare -a IPLISTING    
foo(){    
CONT=0
allIPs=$(ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d ":" -f2)
i=0
while [[ CONT -eq 0 ]] ; do #loop so that it doesn't exit until a valid selection is made
    echo "The following networks were found. Please select one to scan:"; echo
    echo "$allIPs" | while read singleIP ; do
        ((i++))
        IPLISTING[$i]=$(echo $singleIP| cut -d "." -f1-3|sed -e 's/$/.0/')
        echo $i ":" $(echo ${IPLISTING[$i]}) #This works
    done
echo ${IPLISTING[1]} #This does not work. When I echo this it gives me nothing
....
stuff
....
CONT=1
done
}
```

This is for a selection menu so that I can simply pull things out of an array but when I exit this the array is entirely empty. I've tried this with a simple loop in a different test and it works. Additionally I've validated all the commands. I cannot seem to pin down what the issue is. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How is this duplicate? I've already looked at the other and it's not the same issue.

Comment: I'm afraid it is the same as the other Q.  Your inner `while` loop is in a pipe with the `echo` command before it, so the whole thing runs in a subshell. When that exits, `IPLISTING[1]` is no longer set.

Comment: Ok. I tried it on the inner loop and it works but why is it that when the outer while exits I can still access the elements? Is it because I'm piping into while what makes it a subshell?

Comment: You need a select loop in BASH. See some examples online.

Comment: `man bash` says: "*Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).*". Obviously when forking you inherit **in** the variables, but when the (inner) process exits those variable values are lost (no inherit **out**). Simple, isn't it?